# Adjacency matrix with string nodes in Python

Tags: python, matrix, graph-theory

I have a csv file of nodes and a csv file of edges - all the nodes are STRING.
I need help please for how can I build an adjacency matrix of this graph in python?

Example of the data:

```
Nodes csv:
a
b
c
d

Edges csv:
a,b
b,c
a,c
d,a
b,d

I want it to be presented as an adjacency matrix:
  a  b  c  d
a 0  1  1  1
b 1  0  1  1
c 1  1  0  0
d 1  1  0  0
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?  What did not work?  What, actually is the problem?

Comment: Start at the beginning.  Can you read the files?  If yes, then post your code.

Comment: And please post at least a usable sample of the data.

Comment: yes, I can read the files. The first file is read into nodes_df and this is the nodes csv. The second file is read into edges_df and this is the edges csv. I want to build funtion the its input is nodes_list and edges_list "adjacencyMatrixFunc(nodes_list, edge_list):" that take those l ists and print an adjancy matrix. I didn't succeed to do it since all the available information is for integer nodes, and I have string nodes...

Comment: As I said, it will be difficult to help you without knowing what the data looks like, so please edit your question and post samples of data and the corresponding expected output.

Comment: Edited with an example of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok: assuming your nodes and edges have been converted to lists as follows, this works (as you can see, the code is self-explanatory):

```
nodes = ['a','b','c','d']
edges = [('a','b'),('b','c'),('a','c'),('d','a'),('b','d')]

import numpy as np
n = len(nodes)
matrix = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=int)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if (nodes[i],nodes[j]) in edges or (nodes[j],nodes[i]) in edges:
            matrix[i,j] = matrix[j,i] = 1
```

Comment: Do you know how can I cast these matrix values to be int instead of numpy.float64?

Comment: Hello; just modified the code (6th line) in that effect.

Comment: The type wil be numpy.int32 though, not base python int. If for some reason you need this, you can replace the numpy matrix with an array of arrays: matrix = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)], and change matrix[x,y] to matrix[x][y] in the following lines.